# firstdata payment gateway Double charging

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, firstdata, payeezy

I have integrated payeezy API for recurring billing. Everything working good. But most of the payments getting double charging. This is the form

```
<form action="https://checkout.globalgatewaye4.firstdata.com/payment" method="post">

<input name="x_login" value="LOGIN_DATA" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="x_currency_code" value="USD" />
<input name="x_amount" value="15.00" type="hidden">
<input name="x_fp_sequence" value="FP_SEQUENCE" type="hidden">
<input name="x_fp_timestamp" value="TIMESTAMP" type="hidden">
<input name="x_fp_hash" value="HASH" type="hidden">
<input name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="x_cust_id" value='1234'>

<input type="hidden" name="x_type" value="AUTH_CAPTURE" />
<input name="x_recurring_billing_amount" value="15.00" type="hidden">
<input name="x_recurring_billing_id" value="BILLING ID" type="hidden">
<input name="x_recurring_billing" value="TRUE" type="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="x_recurring_billing_start_date" value="START DATE" />
<input type="hidden" name="x_recurring_billing_end_date" value="END DATE" />

<input type="hidden" name="x_first_name" value='FIRST NAME'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_last_name" value='LAST NAME'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_company" value='COMPANY'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_address" value='ADDRESS'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_city" value='CITY'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_state" value='STATE'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_country" value='COUNTRY'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_zip" value='ZIP'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_phone" value='PHONE'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_fax" value='FAX'>
<input type="hidden" name="x_email" value='EMAIL'>

<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Continue to Secure Payment Form" >
```

Please let me know if anything wrong in this input values.

I have attached an image of the transaction[Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESUbH.png).

Thanks,
Vipin

Comment: Those transactions are 12 minutes apart. What makes you think the problem is with your form?

Comment: I am not sure the problem with my form. Looks like it is correct. But I am not able to identify the exact issue. My client said they paid only one time and its double charged. Is it something related to my firstdata payment settings?

Comment: That was a setting error. I have fixed the issue. Thank you!